# jQuery effects combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I want to apply highlight and remove effects to the same dom. One after the other. Unfortunately the highlight effect is not visible as the remove gets triggered immediately after.

Any idea to delay the remove action?

```
$("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").effect("highlight", {}, 4000)
$("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").remove()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, `.remove()` can't be delayed. It is one of those functions that triggers right away, meaning `.delay()` does nothing.

However, JavaScript's `setTimeout()` function will:

```
$('#g').click(function(){
$("#hi").hide("highlight", {}, 4000)
setTimeout('$("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").remove();', 4100)
});
```

Here's an [example of this on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/W9NHT/1/).

Comment: Thanks. I removed the remove action and works just fine with your syntax. that's all I need.Thanks

Comment: Your Welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Is `effect` a jQuery PlugIn ? I cant find any documentation of that function on the jQuery Site.

Use [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) because you got a callback after your animation is done.

```
  $("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
  }, 4000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").remove();
  });
```

**Update**

like Shawn31313 said

```
effect(..)
```

is part of jQuery UI and this function also supports "callbacks" after the effect is done.
[jQuery UI Effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/)

**hope this helps**

Comment: Effect comes with jquery UI I believe.

Answer (score 1):

.effect() have callback argument that will get called after effect finishes. See [effect demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#option-callback).

```
$("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").effect("highlight", {}, 4000, function() {
    $("#<%= dom_id(@stock) %>").remove();
});
```